# What is the elegant way of applying function to two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I am interested in finding the most concise elegant way of doing the following:
We have a function `fun[x1,x2]` 
and two lists:

```
ls1={a1,a2,a3,a4,......}
```

and

```
ls2={b1,b2,b3,b4,......}
```

I want my result to be:

```
 Rslt={{{a1,fun[a1,b1]},{a1,fun[a1,b2]},{a1,fun[a1,b3]},.......},
        {{a2,fun[a2,b1]},{a2,fun[a2,b2]},{a2,fun[a2,b3]},.......}, 
        {{a3,fun[a3,b1]},{a3,fun[a3,b2]},{a3,fun[a3,b3]},.......},......}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `Table[{i, func[i, j]}, {i, ls1}, {j, ls2}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, that's an easy one to write and maybe a bit harder to understand:

```
ls1 = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
ls2 = {b1, b2, b3, b4};

Outer[{#1, func[##]} &, ls1, ls2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this works as well `Outer[{#, func[##]} &, ls1, ls2]`

Comment: @José I wonder what you wanted to say by that.

Comment: Oh, no need of adding ‘1’ to ‘#’, nothing special.